# Farming gold in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the fastest way to get gold in Diablo 3?

Comment: That is not true, the items on AH don't appear out of no where, you can earn a lot of gold selling leveling equipment(especially weapons with high base stats and/or dps)

Comment: @Blem that sounds a lot like an answer. Maybe you should make it one?

Comment: Except that it *is* true until you're deep into infernal. It's better to farm gold from trash mobs and AH any interesting drops you run across rather than trying to hunt down champion/rare mobs and kill them for their loot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### THIS ANSWER IS CURRENT AS OF PATCH 2.0/REAPER OF SOULS

The answer to this question is now a lot simpler than it was when the Auction House was around, and different difficulties were more ambiguous about their effects. Now you can increase your gold per hour in **THREE** primary ways:

### Bounties and Nephalem rifts

After completing Act V, you will unlock access to Adventure mode, which will allow you to undertake bounties and occasionally Nephalem Rifts. In each of these modes, you are given a specific task to undertake in certain parts of the game, usually killing a certain mob or clearing an area. Once you do that, you are rewarded a substantial sum of XP and gold, in addition to any that you earn along the way by killing mobs or completing a side quest like a cursed chest. In Nephalem rifts, particularly, mobs come fast and furious which create ideal conditions for lots of gold drops.

### Raise the difficulty

The higher the difficulty, the more gold will drop. However, it is up to you to find the sweet spot between what difficulty allows you to move quick enough to make the bonus worthwhile. i.e. is it better for you to run 4 bounties per hour on Torment I or 6 per hour on Master?

- **Normal**   Enemies have 100% health, do 100% damage. No XP or gold drop
  bonuses.
- **Hard** Enemies have 200% health, do 130% damage. XP gains and gold
  drops both boosted by 75%.
- **Expert**   Enemies have 320% health, do 189% damage. XP gains and gold
  drops both boosted by 100%.
- **Master**   Enemies have 512% health, do 273% damage. XP gains and gold
  drops both boosted by 200%.
- **Torment I**    Enemies have 819% health, do 396% damage. XP gains and gold
  drops both boosted by 300%.
- **Torment II**   Enemies have 1,311% health, do 575% damage. XP gains and
  gold drops both boosted by 400%.
- **Torment III**  Enemies have 2,097% health, do 833% damage. XP gains and
  gold drops both boosted by 550%.
- **Torment IV**   Enemies have 3,355% health, do 1,208% damage. XP gains and
  gold drops both boosted by 800%.
- **Torment V**    Enemies have 5,369% health, do 1,752% damage. XP gains and
  gold drops both boosted by 1,150%.
- **Torment VI**   Enemies have 8,590% health, do 2,540% damage. XP gains and
  gold drops both boosted by 1,600%.

The table above comes from [this site.](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/diablo-iii-reaper-souls-guide-loot-2-0-changes/#ixzz2xZJSQzZc)

### Increase your gold find percentage

As in vanilla D3, increasing your gold find stats will provide an increase to the amount of gold dropped. You should balance this, however, with finding gear that makes you more effective at killing mobs, thereby increasing your throughput. Luckily, on most gear, gold find is considered a "secondary stat" and does not take away from primary skills like dexterity or crit chance. You'll need to find your own balance of quantity of kills vs. quality of kills.

You can also increase your gold find through the Paragon leveling system. Keep in mind, as above, you'll be taking points from other areas that might make you more effective in combat, such as "life on hit". But this is a good way to increase your gold find without finding specialized gear. Since you can reset paragon points at will, this may be a good way to increase gold find on difficulties where you don't need the other utility stats.

Answer (score 11):

To get pure gold the two biggest factors are how much gold find you have and what act/difficulty you are in(higher is better untill you reach Inferno where Act wont matter). The key facter here is balancing the amount of gold find you have so you can still kill high level monsters. You can also make a pure gold find set(also works for magic find) and after clearing an area for monsters equip your set and go open chests and destroying things that can contain gold/items.

But a better way of getting gold is using the AH, there is no cost to putting items up and there are plenty of people buying items, atm I would recommend focusing on magic and rare level 45-59 weapons with high dps and high damage stats(str/dex/int), but other items with good stats also work. The reason for the level is that people need to be high enough to have gold, and once you hit 60 it is a lot harder farming for the easy selling items (higher standards). Don't be to greedy, it is better to sell a lot of items at a lower price than a few at high, if you can sell 5 weapons at 50k each you will make more than selling 1 at 200k in the same period. Just try and make sure to always use the 10 item slots you can have up on AH.

Comment: Also accessories with +damage (e.g., +4-8 damage, you can't search for this attribute, but it's there) and decent stats (primary stat + vit) and a socket can go for pretty decent prices (10-20k++ per accessory). Additional attributes, such as +Life per hit/after kill, Magic Find, et al, can significantly improve the value of the accessory as well..

Comment: Beware that the upcoming [magic find swap changes](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5338426/Magic_Find_Gear_Swapping-03_07_2012) could possibly render this strategy useless:

Comment: I don't agree that you should sell more items at a lower price. First, you only have a limited number of auctions, so you cannot sell items for very cheap because the can use all your slots. But more importantly, cheap items are not worth my time. I'd rather spend my time farming than selling 10-30k items. Because eventually you will find a multi-million item. Personally, the vast majority of my revenue comes from selling >1M items.

Comment: @pinouchon the example values are nearly 2 months old. The main point is not the number, but the scaling of the numbers. If it makes you happy it might as well say it is better to sell 5 items at 1M than 1 item at 4M in the same time, the point is it is better to have a higher turnover than trying to sell one high value item at a higher cost. Also the better an item is the less chance of it loosing value over time is where the mediocre items will loose value over time so it is better to get rid of it to get new items.

Answer (score 4):

Stockpile gear with `Gold Finding` stats on it so that your `Gold Find` is high (you can view this under `Character Sheet`->`Gold Find`.

You then have some choices. The higher difficulty mobs, as well as higher Act mobs, drop more gold then their predecessor. However, they get tougher to kill, taking longer.

I have no proof of this, but it seems to me that Act III is the best Act to farm anything - gold, XP, items, etc. because it appears to me to have the most amount of mobs that are still somewhat squishy.

If you are really looking to farm, **I'd recommend Act III of the highest difficulty that you can do**, and as others mentioned, don't just focus on pure gold drops; items can sell very well in the AH.

And remember that not only rares have great stats! A magic (blue) item can carry the best stats in the game.

[Here's an  official blue post stating so](http://blues.incgamers.com/Posts/10/1/40/819/161558/blue-respone-as-to-why-blueslegendaries-etc):

> Legendary items are commonly not going to be the best items. It's a
>   title that denotes a named item, with set stats, and a unique model.
>   It does not mean they're the best items.
>
> Completely random rares will be the best items in the game if they
>   roll up the right stats.

Comment: Uh...  "A magic (blue) item can carry the best stats in the game." is wrong. A *rare (yellow)* item can be the best item in the game, not a magic blue item. Blue items cannot be better than the best yellow items, they have fewer magical properties.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what my friend and I have been doing, proven success (roughly 220k/hr, tomes, potions, and the occasional magic/rare item) without any real combat. You'll need a gold find set for this to work. *Inferno will yield the best results **by far***.

1. Wear your normal gear and start at the end of Reign of the Black King in Act 1
2. Fight your way to the Royal Crypts
3. Switch to your gold find set
4. Change whatever skills you want to maximize your item destruction ability
5. Run around the area destroying all the vases, coffins, etc.
6. Stop when you get to the point where the Skeleton King activates those four pillars.
7. Teleport back to New Tristram
8. Leave the game
9. Resume the game
10. Repeat steps 4-9 as long as you want

I made about 900k yesterday running this for a few hours and auctioning off a few rares I found. Fair warning, though, this gets *boring* fast, so put on a podcast or something to entertain yourself during the process.

I bet this is going to get nerfed soon if it hasn't been already, since I wouldn't necessarily call vases or coffins "monsters", the +% gold find from monsters won't apply to random items for much longer.

Comment: Something to note: As of the most recent patch, this method doesn't work any more (or so I've heard). They removed gold drop from certain sections of vases/jars, and the Royal Crypts was one of the areas affected.

Comment: Drop rates from the Ashes pots was severely nerfed, so this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it helps to have a Gold Set (i.e. armour and items whose stats increase gold finding abilities).  I find that battling mobs which contain one or more spawners tends to work well.  The weaker creatures will keep coming as long as you don't kill the spawner (I've heard them referred to as Lieutenants).

**The Dahlgur Oasis (Act II) is full of Spawners.**  Look for the blue guys who launch the slow moving fireballs.  If you stay away from them, they'll just keep spawning little blue guys endlessly.  What's better is that even if you get hit by the Spawners' slow-moving fireballs, the little guys you kill will inevitably drop health anyway.  Just remember, if you bring a companion, do your best to keep him/her from rushing the Spawners.

**The Forgotten Ruins (Act II)**  When you first enter the ruins, there's a green stone spire that will churn out spiders.  As long as you don't hit the spire, the spiders will keep coming.  These spiders are a bit tougher than the blue guys and (I would imagine) yield more gold.  There are another three or four of these spawning monuments throughout the ruins.  As a matter of fact, the whole map of the Forgotten Ruins has some great mobs.  The last time I played it I made about 6,000 gold without a dedicated Gold Set.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's just me, but I seem to get the most gold dropping from undead mobs (mostly in act 1 hell/inferno). With 300% additional gold (including 5NV stacks) I can easily pull in 200k an hour.

Clear out the 3 crypts in the Cemetery of the Forsaken, clear the large areas throughout act 1, then clear the 3 levels up to the butcher (as well as the jailer area in between levels 2 and 3 of the dungeons). It's fairly easy, even with a large amount of gold find and nerfed stats.

Answer (score 1):

Start at the Heart of Sin quest in act 3 on Hell difficulty. Teleport to Rakki's Crossing, run through until the end of the crossing, teleport to Core of Arreat, kill demons, kill Azmodan. On hell, he has a chance to drop ilvl63 and you will make about 400K+ an hour if you do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Stockpile gear with +gold finding stats, then go out and farm mobs.  I'm not sure if there is anywhere that is best for farming.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get the Gibbering Gemstone from the Caverns of Frost in Act 3 at nightmare difficulty. The amount of drop and monster quantity was staggering. If I can ever get there at Hell difficulty, I think I'll farm there a little before going on

Comment: I've been doing the exact same thing, but I've only picked up 22k worth. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*Given that the AH is in the game, I will assume that gold is equivalent to wealth.*

Here are a few techniques I tried to accumulate wealth the game, sorted by the rate at which you generate it. (better rates first)

- Buy gold directly from the RMAH.

It's very fast. But you have to spend money

- Flip items on the Gold AH / RMAH.

You need a good knowledge of the enonomy of the AH. But you can make good amounts of wealth in the game with this method. Look for items with those stats:
Crit chance / crit damage / atk speed / main stat / all resist / vit and learn about combination makes items expensive. I make about 5euros on average every time I spend 15min to flip items on the RMAH. So far, I have been successfull flipping windup wands (atk speed, ap per crit, crit damage, and/or socket) and rings and amulets. The main drawback is that is it boring.

In my opinion, the rate you can achieve is between 1 to 10eur per hour with this technique.

- Farm inferno act 3

You need to get good gear to be able to complete act3 efficiently. I am using a [windup wizard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awJNb76H5Qs) for that because I think it is by far the most efficient farming build for a given gear price. You can jump from elite to elite by refreshing your [wormhole](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/teleport) cooldown on white mobs.

Another good farming spec is the whirlwind barbarian. [Farming act 3 with a WW barb](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8svPYxbi0o) is the  main method of wealth farming of Kripparian.

Depending on you build, magic find and luck, you should be between 1M and 10M per hour with this technique. But you are more often close to 1M which make it inferior to AH item flipping in my opinion.

- Gold farm

I have never tried any of those methods, but they are boring and inefficient in my view.

[Here is a good guide about wealth increasing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7uI0dpirUI)